# Implementing onSavedInstanceState stops FragmentStatePagerAdapter working

Tags: android, fragmentstatepageradapter

In my activity, I had found I needed to store state for one of my tabs in a tabbed view.  This was the result of a search bar, and I needed an Activity to receive and store the data.

Although my application was working before hand, when I implemented in my Activity

```
public void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState ){
    ArrayList<SearchData.SearchDataSerial> sdSerial = new ArrayList<SearchData.SearchDataSerial>();
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < mSearchData.size() ; i++ ){
        SearchData item = mSearchData.get(i);
        SearchData.SearchDataSerial elem = new SearchData.SearchDataSerial( item );
        sdSerial.add( elem );
    }
    outState.putParcelableArrayList( "searchterms", sdSerial );


    Log.d( TAG, "OnSaveInstanceState" );
}
```

It broke the persistence of all the other fragments in the tabs.

Also if in onCreate for the activity, if I had to change my code to this to keep the pages loading.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /* ... not relevant */
    // if( savedInstanceState == null ) { /* had to comment out this line */
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SlidingTabsBasicFragment fragment = new SlidingTabsBasicFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.tabbed_layout_main, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    //} /* had to comment out this line */
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        loadSavedData( savedInstanceState );
    }

    setupActionBar();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#asem) say:

> Caution: You must always call the superclass implementation of
>   onSaveInstanceState() so the default implementation can save the state
>   of the view hierarchy.

So the correct code should look like...

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState ){
    super.onSaveInstanceState( outState ); /* Needs to be here for framework to work */
    ArrayList<SearchData.SearchDataSerial> sdSerial = new ArrayList<SearchData.SearchDataSerial>();
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < mSearchData.size() ; i++ ){
        SearchData item = mSearchData.get(i);
        SearchData.SearchDataSerial elem = new SearchData.SearchDataSerial( item );
        sdSerial.add( elem );
    }
    outState.putParcelableArrayList( "searchterms", sdSerial );


Log.d( TAG, "OnSaveInstanceState" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks - can I add the correct code to your answer?  I had spent a couple of hours on this, and posted to answer myself.

Comment: Sure, go ahead.